# not able to add logo in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am editing an html template, the logo dimensions of the template is lower than my logo, i added my logo to the template but its not displaying,

```css
@media (max-width: 673px) {
  #logo {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

#header #logo h1 {
  font-size: 34px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#header #logo h1 a,
#header #logo h1 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 4px solid #7c32ff;
}

#header #logo img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #header #logo h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  #header #logo img {
    max-height: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="header-top">
  <div class="container box_1170">
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">
          <img src="img/long_logo.png" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-trigger">
        <a href="#" class="search">
          <i class="lnr lnr-magnifier" id="search"></i></a>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

my logo dimesnions are 500px*280
i just want to add my logo somehow, is there any way.how can i fix it?

Comment: When you put `#` before a css selector it is treated as 'ID' selector, `.` is used in css for class selector. Try replacing `#logo` with `.logo` in your css. Also check browser developer console for errors. You can open developer console in most of modern browsers by pressing "F12" key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using classes and calling IDs on your .css

Did you try creating a `<div>` with a class and adding your logo inside the div ? This way you could manipulate the div dimensions and the logo itself until it fits.

A simple example :.

CSS :

```
.logo {
    background-image: url("img/long_logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

BODY :

```
<section class="header-top">
    <div class="container box_1170">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <a href="index.html">
                        <div class="logo"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 search-trigger">
                <a href="#" class="search">
                        <i class="lnr lnr-magnifier" id="search"></i></a>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS styles, you are using `id` selector, but the HTML template has more of classes.

Also make sure the picture you want to include in the template is within the `img/` folder

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong CSS Selectors.

For example, if you have assigned a class to your HTML elements like as follows:

```
<div class="header">
</div>
```

You should be using "." to apply CSS to it as follows:

```
.header {}
```

Whereas "#" is used to select HTML elements with corresponding ID like so:

*HTML:*

```
<div id="header">
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#header{}
```

Tip - a HTML element can have multiple classes but only one ID.